# AWS Lightsail Windows Server accessing using Public IP

Tags: amazon-lightsail

I am new to AWS Lightsail. I have created Windows Server Instance. Also have mapped to a static IP address. I am trying to accessing using the static IP from internet. It is not getting connected.
Request if you could help me, what other configuration is required to be able to access the server using the static IP.

My instance: Lightsail_KI_Windows_Server_2016-1

request your help.
regards
sandip

Comment: Hi how did you get this done? Can you help me too?